# Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN (openconnect) in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, vpn

I installed Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN (openconnect)

```
$ sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-openconnect is already the newest version.
```

But when I go to add a VPN I don't have the option of adding an openconnect vpn

[image: screenshot]

I had this working with no problems in 14.04 :( 
Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'll poke at this in my VM - I wonder if its broken functionality somewhere that needs a bug filed...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This one helped me: [network-manager-openconnect-gnome](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/network-manager-openconnect-gnome)

Comment: Would it be possible that you might be able to expand on this a bit? It's a start...but maybe say just how to use it, what it's good for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome"   , no reboot needed, and the option appears!  Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic alternative to the Cisco client which I can't get working on Ubuntu 15.04 because it would appear it doesn't expect systemd to be the init manager.  This client was not only easier to use, it was also faster for me.

Comment: @Tramway I had installed it on my ubuntu system, though I can work with commands but, GUI is not opening for me.

Comment: @Manisha is you're using Ubuntu 16.04 see http://askubuntu.com/questions/760864/no-more-anyconnect-compatible-vpn-transport-in-ubuntu-16-04 for details

Comment: @Tramway I am using Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 8):

Install  `network-manager-openconnect` and `network-manager-openconnect-gnome` packages with this command

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

Comment: This worked right away and only took about 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `network-manager-openconnect-gnome` and restart (`sudo service networking restart`)the network-manager. A reboot will fix the problem too.

Comment: You might wish to [edit] your answer to indicate how to restart network manager as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

With respect, Ignacio, I'm not sure what your problem or question is... When you installed the network-manager-openconnect package, that's what gets you to openconnect VPNs -- What's perhaps misleading is that the "right choice" appears in the Network Manager's drop-down list of VPNs to add -- see right under the "VPN" subsection: "Cisco Compatible VPN (vpnc)" <<== That's it! OpenConnect!  I'm sure because I just did this same package install myself earlier this week... ;-)

Does this help you?  -- Lorin

Comment: Lorin I think vpnc and AnyConnect are not the same. After following Tramway guide I was able to configure AnyConnect

Comment: Hi, Ignacio -- Where did you find this Tramway guide? I've been on a deep-dive into VPN on Ubuntu trying to resolve some other problems.  Might it help?  Thank you, sir!

Comment: The other answer, Tramway is the user name