# No more AnyConnect compatible vpn transport in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, vpn, cisco, openconnect

Following my previous experiences with setting up Cisco AnyConnect VPN connections on Ubuntu 14.04 I tried the same approach here by installing packages:

```
sudo apt-get install -y network-manager-openconnect-gnome network-manager-openconnect network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome vpnc vpnc-scripts
```

Even after this an option to create Anyconnect compatible VPN connection does not appear.

Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, stock.

Comment: Note: If anyone thinks they can get by with just `network-manager-openconnect` and not `network-manager-openconnect-gnome` because they're not running GNOME, no: you need the `-gnome` package, because it provides the actual `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-vpn-plugin-openconnect.so` file referred to by the files installed by `network-manager-openconnect` :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had same problem. use package in this page (or build it if you don't trust)
http://tomtomtom.org/networkmanager-openconnect/

It works for me

> On Ubuntu 16.04 the network-manager-openconnect and
>   network-manager-openconnect-gnome plugins are not usable because they
>   are to old to use with the current version of network-manager.
>
> This is the english version of [this guide](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/post/8198598/) from a german ubuntu support
>   forum.
>
> Unofficial built packages are available here:
>
> http://tomtomtom.org/networkmanager-openconnect_1.1.93-1_i386.deb
>
> http://tomtomtom.org/networkmanager-openconnect_1.1.93-1_amd64.deb
>
> NOTE: You won´t get any security updates for this! It is just a
>   workaround until the packages will have been fixed in the official
>   repository!
>
> Using VPN is a security feature - so it is better to build the package
>   manually from source because you don´t know what I put into the
>   packages. :-P
>
> At first remove the unusable packages
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
> ```
>
> You will need the build-dependencies.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get build-dep network-manager-openconnect
> ```
>
> (NOTE: For this the 'deb-src'-Sources in /etc/apt/sources.list must be
>   active.)
>
> You can do this with sed e.g.
>
> ```
> sudo sed -i s/#deb-src/deb-src/g /etc/apt/sources.list
> ```
>
> the new dependency for the new version.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libnm-dev
> ```
>
> and the sourcecode from GNOME project.
>
> ```
> wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/NetworkManager-openconnect/1.1/NetworkManager-openconnect-1.1.93.tar.xz
> ```
>
> Unpack the tarball
>
> ```
> tar -xf NetworkManager-openconnect-1.1.93.tar.xz
> ```
>
> change to the unpacked directory
>
> ```
> cd NetworkManager-openconnect-1.1.93
> ```
>
> and run the configure script.
>
> ```
> ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var
>             --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager/ 
>             --enable-more-warnings=yes --disable-static
> ```
>
> start compiling .
>
> ```
> make
> ```
>
> and install manually
>
> ```
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> install the dependency for use the software
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install openconnect
> ```
>
> or build a package with checkinstall
>
> ```
> sudo checkinstall
> ```
>
> If you do so enter this:
>
> `networkmanager-openconnect` as package name
>
> `adduser, libc6, libdbus-glib-1-2, libglib2.0-0, libnm-glib-vpn1,
>   libnm-util2, network-manager, openconnect` as requirements
>
> and
>
> `network-manager-openconnect, network-manager-openconnect-gnome`
>
> as conflicts.
>
> If you get errormessages by installing the package try
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get -f install
> ```
>
> to resolve unmet dependencies.
>
> To use the software it is necessary to add a systemuser for this
>
> ```
> sudo adduser --system --quiet --home /var/lib/NetworkManager
>              --no-create-home 
>              --gecos "NetworkManager OpenConnect plugin" 
>              --group nm-openconnect}
> ```
>
> At last restart the system.

Comment: Not working for me :(. May try this process again later.

Comment: how do you use this?

Answer (score 21):

I am having the same problem on fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.
You can however connect via terminal :

```
sudo openconnect https://<remote.host.here>
```

after that you should be prompted for user name and password.

Comment: Thanks, but I really need the GUI here. Until that is fixed no Ubuntu 16.04 for me...

Comment: I appreciated the tip! GUI would be nice, but none of the proposed solutions have worked for me. So until the bug is fixed, I at least can have a handy connection script ready.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04, after trying every possible solution google could provide.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but I'm running a non-gui version of Ubuntu Server 16.  If I run this command it just says "Established" and I don't get a prompt back.  How can I connect "in the background"?

Comment: @Scott try "sudo openconnect <host> -u <username> -p <password> -b" see "man openconnect" for more options.

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be an official fix in xenial-proposed. If you [enable pre-release updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) and then do:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

it will start working. Well, it worked for me at least :)

Comment: Yep, this is what I needed to get the pulse secure compatibility working, and for the UI to work with the Ubuntu 17 network settings.

Comment: This is the fix for this issue on 17.10 as well. Need the *-gnome package.

Comment: This is still all I need for Ubuntu 19.10 as well.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Morteza Pourkazemi's answer, the answer works for me, but I need to install the following packages which are required by the `configure` command.

```
sudo apt-get install intltool libxml2-dev libgtk-3-dev libsecret-1-dev libopenconnect-dev network-manager-dev libnm-util-dev libnm-glib-dev libnm-glib-vpn-dev
```

Comment: You misspelled "secret" in "libseceret-1-dev".

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue appears to be that the openconnect plugin is missing a library that network manager now requires.

If I examine the files in /etc/NetworkManager/VPN I see that all of the plugins **except** openconnect have a section that looks like the following:

```
[libnm]
plugin=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-vpn-plugin-vpnc.so
```

network-manager-openconnect-gnome does not appear to provide a similar library and nor does any package in the ubuntu repository.  I think this libnm library is some new requirement of NetworkManager and the version of openconnect in ubuntu doesn't support it yet.

Since I upgraded to 16.04 from 15.10 I still have my VPN connection defined.  I can select and login from the NM GUI.  However I cannot edit the connection via the GUI nor can I add a new VPN connection using openconnect.

Comment: I thought that at first as well, but then I went back and looked at the files in the 15.04 version and it didn't have the plugin either (but worked).  In fact, all of the same files are present in the deb file for 15.04 and 16.04.

Comment: When this happened to me it was because I had installed the "network-manager-vpnc" package, but forgot to also install "network-manager-vpnc-gnome".

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all difficult to do this with a CLI instead of a GUI:

```
openconnect -c ~/path/to/your/client_cert.pem  \
            -k ~/path/to/your/private_key.pem  \
            -b #for background
            $VPN_Address
```

There are also options for giving it your username / password - so throw those in and add the script to startup, and you'll never even have to think about it.

Comment: I am aware of that option but it is not what I want. I want full GUI working without that I can stick with 14.04.

Comment: Well, in case you or anyone out there needs an "get me connected immediately" solution. 
Looks like I'll be rolling back too -_-