# Install Pulse Secure under wine

Tags: software-installation, wine, vpn

Is it possible to install and run Pulse Secure on wine? I have setup the environment variable `WINEARCH=win32` as well as selected Windows 7 under `winecfg`.

When I run `wine start JunosPulse.x86.msi` the installer "fails prematurely" with the following output to terminal:

```
> wine start JunosPulse.x86.msi 
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
> fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
fixme:msi:AutomationObject_GetIDsOfNames Unknown member L"CreateObject", clsid {000c109e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:shell:ShellDispatch_QueryInterface not implemented for {fc4801a3-2ba9-11cf-a229-00aa003d7352} (unknown)
fixme:shell:ShellDispatch_QueryInterface not implemented for {a6ef9860-c720-11d0-9337-00a0c90dcaa9} (unknown)
fixme:shell:ShellDispatch_QueryInterface not implemented for {a6ef9860-c720-11d0-9337-00a0c90dcaa9} (unknown)
fixme:vbscript:do_mcall NULL obj
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"writeTncConfigFile.D7CCF602_E814_4416_8EC5_24D6FEA3289C" returned 1603
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"ExecuteAction" returned 1603
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x65b260) stub
```

The backstory is I have tried both: using openconnect as well as tethering to my Pulse Secure authenticated Android device with no success. I have also tried using the Pulse Secure Debian command-line tool, but it seems that SAML authentication is not supported at this time.

Comment: Just curious if you found a solution to this. I am looking to do the same. I know Junos has a Linux Pulse client now, but I can't get access to download it.

Comment: No, sorry no progress with this. I am using a script provided by my employer to access VPN. It's a good sign that they are supporting Linux now, though!

Comment: is PulseSecure some VPN or no?

Comment: Pulse Secure's Junipers VPN client. You can basically forget to get it working under wine.

Comment: You might be interested to hear, that there is [a native PulseSecure client for linux](https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB40126/). (if you can talk your company into supporting it, is another matter)

Comment: Ultimately what worked best for me was network-manager-openconnect per this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760864/no-more-anyconnect-compatible-vpn-transport-in-ubuntu-16-04/789800#comment1553811_789800

Answer (score 0):

> err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"writeTncConfigFile...." returned 1603

Try to re-/install or upgrade your [.NET framework](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2586) (4.5.3+) as per this [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ee278179-0824-489c-aebd-059d91834d59/net-framework-452-update-fails-with-error-1603?forum=w7itprogeneral).

You can also try to run MSI installer by:

```
wine msiexec /i filename.msi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't install a VPN client in Wine, generally speaking.

VPN software relies on some network adapter in the kernel to pass traffic to and from the network stack. On Linux this is commonly a TUN/TAP device, which passes traffic to a user space program. Windows has a defined interface for network adapters - which is **not** equal to Linux interface.

So a driver made for Windows **will not work** in wine. You can not install your Windows VPN client in wine and make it work, no matter what you do. You **need** to make openconnect work, or run a windows virtual machine. It's possible you could make your Windows machine forward traffic to your Linux machine.