# Hostnames on VPN stop resolving after a period of time even though /etc/resolv.conf is correct

Tags: vpn, dns, openvpn, resolv.conf

I use VPN to connect to a subnet (192.168.3.0/24) and get the DNS pushed from the VPN server.

It works well however after a period of time, hostnames on the 192.168.3.0/24 subnet no longer resolve.

I've checked `/etc/resolv.conf` and it does contain `nameserver 192.168.3.1`.

What should I look into to find what more about why this is happening?
The client is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Update: When I reload the networking service on the client, the subnet resolves again.

Comment: I saw a similar problem with networkmanager and openvpn. it's gone ofr now.

Comment: Which VPN client are you using?

Comment: OpenVPN. I updated the post with a workaround (reloading the network service). Still don't understand what causes it or how to prevent it though...

Answer (score 0):

see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838948/16-10-fail-to-resolve-dns): Looks like a problem with Networkmanager and dnsmasq.
But when i try to remove dnsmasq-base it would remove network-manager and teh desktop too. So not working here. BTW I have upgraded form 16.04 to 16.10.