# Wired connection not using DNS (Wireless is fine) 16.10

Tags: networking, internet, 16.10, wired, opendns

I have set my wired connection to OpenDNS. Without the OpenDNS, I cant access BBC.com. But even with the OpenDNS, my wired connection still cant access BBC.com.It would say page not found.

My wireless connection to the same modem can access BBC just fine. So it seems like despite the settings, my wired connection is not using the DNS

[image]
The BBC is blocked by some ISP in my country for publishing liberal articles (Freedom of the press is not respected by my government), so it's not the problem of BBC blocking my IP, but a problem from my end of the connection.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/838948/16-10-fail-to-resolve-dns

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a problem (in recent memory) using OpenDNS and it does provide some measure of security against some of the hacking going on.

It's possible that 404- page not found errors are due to your IP being blocked by the target site and has nothing to do with DNS.

To test if DNS is working, type:

dig bbc.com

If it returns the IP for bbc.com, the DNS piece is OK.  To check if a particular DNS server is serving up the correct lookup type:

dig @208.67.222.222 bbc.com # Where @ = the desireed DNS lookup server

Many web sites (e,g, Craigslist) block queries for proxy IPs so you will see this problem a lot if you use a proxy server or go through a VPN.

Comment: `dig bbc.com` returns this ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> bbc.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 13635
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bbc.com.   IN A

;; Query time: 28 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 16 16:42:05 ICT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 36

Comment: Ah yes, among that jungle of words I manage to read "status: SERVFAIL".

Comment: dig @208.67.222.222 bbc.com returns `status: NOERROR`. It's not the DNS that's the problem. The problem is my connection is not using that DNS :(